Significance of the publishing date of a patent
If a patent application has been filed but has not but published, then it can still be used to block a later patent application for the exact same invention.
However, what if a later patent application is for a very similar invention? If the unpublished application cannot be used as prior art, will this similar application be granted?

You say

If a patent application has been filed but has not but published, then it can still be used to block a later patent application for the exact same invention.

That is not true. An unpublished application, assuming it is not disclosed elsewhere, is not visible to the examiner.
It is possible for a later filed application to be granted - possibly due to an expedited examination - before an earlier filed application has been published even under the 18 month publication and definitely under a non publication request.
The wrong person will get a patent. Once granted it will take some process to invalidate it. The most expedient way is via an IPR.


If a patent application has been filed but has not but published, then it can still be used to block a later patent application for the exact same invention.

Are you sure? If the first application goes abandoned without publication, and its inventors have not published elsewhere, I'm pretty sure the undisclosed invention is up for grabs again to others who may independently discover it.
I'm not sure about the case where the first application is not yet abandoned. Holding up a later patent application because of an earlier application that the Examiner can't disclose the existence or contents of to the later applicant sounds a bit slimy. The policy should be to allow the later application to issue if it prosecuted faster, and become invalid when and if the earlier application is published. However, I must stress that I don't actually know what the Office does in such cases.
Note that all this matters only if applicants are using non-publication requests to hold off publication. Normally, applications publish significantly sooner than they are examined, so all prior applications will have published by the time a particular application is examined.

However, what if a later patent application is for a very similar invention? If the unpublished application cannot be used as prior art, will this similar application be granted?

I assume you're talking about the difference between 102 and 103. As far as I know there is no difference in treatment between what can be considered prior for 102 or 103 purposes (in the U.S.).

In the U.S. prior art for 102 and 103 is the same. In the EPO something unpublished at the time of your filing (that is published during the pendency of your filing) can’t be used as prior art for lack of inventive step (analogous to obviousness) analysis.
